# SynchronizationContext Problems with Prism DelegateCommand created on a background thread

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, synchronizationcontext

I moved the creation of one of my classes to a background thread in my C#/WPF app.  It exposes a Prism `DelegateCommand` object.  Suddenly my app starts crashing.  I think my hack of a fix is the wrong way to go but I don't know a better one.  Can someone tell me?

This is the command I create in the constructor.

```
AnalyzeCmd = new DelegateCommand(() => Analyze(), () => CanAnalyze)
    .ObservesProperty(() => CanAnalyze);
```

When I used to create this in the UI thread, everything worked fine, no matter what thread changed the `CanAnalyze` property.  But now, whenever `CanAnalyze` changes on a background thread, my application crashes.  The button to which the command is bound is complaining about lack of access of the current thread.

Looking at Prism's `DelegateCommandBase`, I can see why.  `DelegateCommandBase` captures the `SynchronizationContext` in its constructor and then tries to invoke  `CanExecuteChanged` on that context whenever it needs to.

```
protected DelegateCommandBase()
{
    _synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
}
protected virtual void OnCanExecuteChanged()
{
    var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        if (_synchronizationContext != null && _synchronizationContext != SynchronizationContext.Current)
            _synchronizationContext.Post((o) => handler.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty), null);
        else
            handler.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

But on my background thread, that's the wrong context.   And there does not seem to be any way for me to manually set the `_synchronizationContext` member of my `DelegateCommand` object.  Once it is constructed, that thing is locked in.

About the only way I could make this work was to "fake" the context while creating the commands.  This looks terrible even to me but it does make the `CanExecuteChanged` get sent to the correct thread.

```
// Fake the UI thread's context for `DelegateCommand`
var prevCtx = SynchronizationContext.Current;
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(Application.Current.Dispatcher));

AnalyzeCmd = new DelegateCommand(() => Analyze(), () => CanAnalyze)
    .ObservesProperty(() => CanAnalyze);

// Now restore the previous context

SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(prevCtx);
```

From what I have read the user generally should not be setting the Synchronization context in a WPF application.  So is there a better, recommended way to do this?

Comment: I think you should avoid instantiating UI related class on background threads. Can you explain why you do that?

Comment: It is inside a collection inside another object that is not created until the user navigates to a display, but is heavy enough to need to be created asynchronously so as not to hold up the responsiveness of the application.  It is part of a push to make the application more responsive.  I would love to be able to redesign things but that's not really in the cards now.  If the command object just allowed me to pass in the synchronization context in the constructor as an optional argument, that would solve my issue but sadly, it does not

Comment: I did find another workaround.  My class (a view-model) implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and its implementation uses an optional saved `SynchronizationContext` in much the same way that its `DelegateCommand` member does.  But it also allows me  set that context myself in the constructor.  So although I cannot control the destination thread of the `CanExecuteChanged` event, I *can* control the destination thread of the `PropertyChanged` event that triggers it.    Still a hack but much less of one.  No calling `SetSynchronizationContext`